# OpenCV findContours of points vector

Tags: c++, opencv

I've got a vector of 2D points and I need to find all the contours formed by these points. Unfortunately, `cv::findContours` can't handle an array of points, it requires a binary image.

So the question is there any workaround to get contours of points? Maybe it is possible to form a binary image using the points and then use this image in `cv::findContours` function?
Please advise here.

Comment: Are you are looking for the convex hull ? See http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/convex-hull.html

Comment: As I've understood from your link, convexHull doesn't return all the contours, but only one of them

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of image, you can create a binary image of zeros and fill all the 2D points with value 255. Then use **cv::findContours** to find all the contours in binary image.

Following code snippet may help you:

```
// If pts is your array of float points and r,c are number of rows and columns of image
//calculate total number of points in array
int n = sizeof(pts) / sizeof(*pts);
//if points are stored in vector, then use n = pts.size()
//create binary image
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(Size(c, r), CV_8UC1);
//fill all the points with value 255
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    image.at<uchar>(p[i]) = 255;
}
//find all contours in binary image and save in contours variale
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(image, contours, hierarchy, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

Comment: I know the image size. Could you please describe in details your workaround? I've got float coordinates, so don't know how to fill all the 2D float points

Comment: I have edited my answer and added code snippet. It may help you.

Comment: Invert x and y... or directly use p[i] to access the image

Comment: Yes, use image.at<uchar>(p[i].y, p[i].x) = 255; or
image.at<uchar>(p[i]) = 255;

Comment: looks like the solution. I wasn't able to get correct image size, but I'll try to do it tonight and update you with results. Thanks.

Comment: I set image size 1000x1000 just for test. Loop finished successfully, but an error failed on findContours. That's what I see on console screen: `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in cv::_OutputArray::create, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1486`

Comment: you can find solution of this error here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646855/opencv-findcontours-function-error]